How can I create an interactive image carousel where clicking a button on an image displays the next image in the carousel?
I have created one react.js component to create carousel. And second component that show button (Hotspot) on image.
But I did not manage to combine both.
I created first component called ImageCarousel.js. With this I managed to created carousel.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

const ImageCarousel = ({ images }) => {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);

  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    afterChange: (index) => setCurrentSlide(index)
  };

  const handleOverlayClick = (action) => {
    // Handle different actions based on the image
    if (action === 'go-to-next') {
        const nextSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % images.length;
        setCurrentSlide(nextSlide)
      // Do something when the setting action is clicked
    }
  };

  return (
    <Slider {...settings}>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <div key={index} style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
          <img src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />
          {index === currentSlide && image.overlay && (
            <div
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: image.overlay.top,
                left: image.overlay.left,
                transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
                padding: '10px',
                borderRadius: '5px'
              }}
              onClick={() => handleOverlayClick(image.overlay.action)}

            >
              {image.overlay.text}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </Slider>
  );
};

export default ImageCarousel;

Then I created second component ImageWithHotspots.js. With this I got a button on image but only managed to do in one image and cannot add second image.
import React from 'react';

const ImageWithHotspots = ({ src, hotspots }) => {
  const handleHotspotClick = (action) => {
    if (action === 'go-to-next') {
      // Implement logic to move to the next slide
      console.log('Moving to the next slide');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
      <img src={src} alt="Image" style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }} />
      {hotspots.map((hotspot, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: hotspot.top,
            left: hotspot.left,
            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            backgroundColor: '#2142E7',
            color: 'white',
            padding: '5px 10px',
            borderRadius: '5px',
            zIndex: '1'
          }}
          onClick={() => handleHotspotClick(hotspot.action)}
        >
          {hotspot.text}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageWithHotspots;

I want it work like this
